# Uncountable "relatively independent" subset of finite dimensional vector spaces over an uncountable field

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space over an uncountable field ; then does there always exist an uncountable subset $S$ of $V$ such that any $n$ vectors of $S$ are linearly independent ? ( I can prove that there always exist a countably infinite subset with such property but having trouble in proving whether there is an uncountable set or not )

Comment: The claim sounds fishy in the countable case too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : But I have proved it when the ground field is infinite ( no need for uncountable ground field then )

Answer (score 2):

The points on the curve $t\mapsto (1,t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^{n-1})$ satisfy this. The determinant of any matrix whose rows consist of $n$ distinct points on this curve is nonzero, as it is the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) of the elements.